# 5 Examples of game Development technology helping/using movie animation technology and vice versa

Tags: unity, animation, game-industry, unreal, maya

I wish to have information on the technology of game development say Unreal being used in the movie industry.
I also wish to have information on the technology of movie industry being used in the game development industry.

I guess there is a lot of similarity, yet a lot of differences between the games development industry and movie animation software industry. I have also seen companies related to the movie animation industry hiring Unity or Unigene or Unreal developers. I have also heard that models made in a specific software say Maya are used in the game development industry or vice versa. Please share a detailed information about this.

Please give 5 examples, where a certain movie house used game development technology or vice versa. Say for example, (hypothetically), Shrek being made in Unreal, etc.

Comment: Edited to make it specific.

Comment: Even if restricted to 5 examples, this is still totally opinion-based, which is [off-topic](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Stack Exchange sites are about questions that *have correct answers*. You might want to ask on a [more discussion-oriented site](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1840/7804).

Comment: @Anko, I agree this might not be specific, but it is not opinion - based. Please correct me if I am wrong. Else, I withdraw my question.

Comment: There are no objective criteria by which to choose 5 examples, hence this is subjective a.k.a. opinion-based.